# what is the remainder when this sum is divided by 6

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

This is another problem I don't know how to do in a contest. Can anyone give me an hint or show me how to solve the problem? What is the trick here?

> If 738 consecutive integers are added together, where the 178th number in the sequence is 4,256,815, what is the remainder when this sum is divided by 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of the $6$ consecutive integers $n,n+1,\ldots,n+5$ is $6n+15$, which leaves a remainder of $3$ when divided by $6$, so the sum of $12$ consecutive integers is divisible by $6$. $738=12\cdot 61+6$, so we can divide the $738$ consecutive integers into $61$ blocks of $12$ consecutive integers and a block of $6$ consecutive integers. The $61$ blocks of $12$ consecutive integers have sums divisible by $6$, and the remaining block leaves a remainder of $3$, so the whole sum has a remainder of $3$.